# Trying to find time where an average temp is reached in a cylinder?

Tags: heat-transfer

My problem consists of a cylinder with 2D heat transfer. In the radial direction the biot number is less than 0.1 so uniform temp distribution is assumed, however in the planar direction it is not. I used the planar formula for biot number less than 0.1 which consists of a sum? How would I find the average temp and the temp at the center of this cylinder? What is the difference between these two and how could I go about it?

Comment: Radial is the direction along the lines that would be a radius to the circle part of the cylinder.  If you make an assumption such as uniform temperature along that axis (dT/dr=0 for all r), you might as well stop treating it like a cylinder.  Did you perhaps mean along the tangential directions?